# How many times is the DBRecordReader getting created?

Tags: database, hadoop

Below is what I think of the hadoop framework processing text files. Please correct me if I am going wrong somewhere.

Each mapper acts on an input split which contains some records.
For each input split a record reader is getting created which starts reading records from the input split.
If there are n records in an input split the map method in the mapper is called n times which in turn reads a key-value pair using the record reader.

Now coming to the databases perspective
I have a database on a single remote node. I want to fetch some data from a table in this database. I would configure the parameters using DBConfigure and mention the input table using DBInputFormat. Now say if my table has 100 records in all, and I execute an SQL query which generates 70 records in the output.

I would like to know :

How are the InputSplits getting created in the above case (database) ?

What does the input split creation depend on, the number of records which my sql query generates or the total number of records in the table (database) ?

How many DBRecordReaders are getting created in the above case (database) ?

Answer (score 2):

How are the InputSplits getting created in the above case (database)?

```
// Split the rows into n-number of chunks and adjust the last chunk
// accordingly
  for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
    DBInputSplit split;
    if ((i + 1) == chunks)
      split = new DBInputSplit(i * chunkSize, count);
    else
      split = new DBInputSplit(i * chunkSize, (i * chunkSize)
          + chunkSize);
    splits.add(split);
  }
```

There is the how, but to understand what it depends on let's take a look at chunkSize:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
results = statement.executeQuery(getCountQuery());
results.next();

long count = results.getLong(1);

int chunks = job.getConfiguration().getInt("mapred.map.tasks", 1);
long chunkSize = (count / chunks);
```

So chunkSize takes the count = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName` and divides this by chunks = `mapred.map.tasks` or 1 if it is not defined in the configuration.

Then finally, each input split will have a `RecordReader` created to handle the type of database you are reading from for instance: `MySQLDBRecordReader` for MySQL database.

For more info check out the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/DBInputFormat.java#DBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.DBInputSplit,org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29)

Comment: So does that mean that if I have 100 records in all in my table and the number of map tasks are set to say 3 then the number of chunks and hence the number of input splits created in this case are 3. 1st chunk with 33 records, 2nd chunk with 33 records and 3rd chunk with 34 records [adjusted]. Hence we will also be creating 3 records readers in all i.e. one for each chunk/inputsplit ?

Comment: That's exactly right. Notice the comment in the very first code block above _Split the rows into n-number of chunks and adjust the last chunk accordingly_ so if you work through the code using the chunkSize = 33 and chunk = 3 you will end up with what you described above. The last map (map number 3) will trigger (i + 1) == chunks and the final split will be (chunkSize = 33 times i = 2) = 66(start) to 100(end) records long ---which is 34! Yei Math!

Comment: Did I answer your question to your satisfaction? If so, please select my answer. It motivates us to go the extra mile

Answer (score 1):

It appears @Engineiro explained it well by taking the actual hadoop source. Just to answer, number of DBRecordReader is equal to number of map tasks.

To explain further, the Hadoop Map side framework creates an instance of DBRecordReader for each Map task, in case where the child JVM is not reused for further Map tasks. In other words, the number of input splits is equals to the value of map.reduce.tasks in case of DBInputFormat. So, each map Task's record Reader has the meta information to construct the query to get subset of data from the table. Each Record Reader executes a pagination type of SQL which is similar to the below.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*,ROWNUM dbif_rno FROM ( select * from emp ) a WHERE rownum <= 6 + 7 ) WHERE dbif_rno >= 6
```

The above SQL is for the second Map tasks to return the rows between 6 and 13

To generalize for any type of Input formats, the number of Record Readers is equals to the number of Map Tasks.

Comment: Is there a way to know this metadata and how the example query that you is getting constructed ? It would be of great help ...

Comment: The input split for the DBInputFormat holds the start and end row which is very similar to the pagination keys such as start and end row. This is the meta information given to the MapTask's DBRecordReader which uses this information and constructs the SQL and executes. For for information, look at the method nextKeyValue() at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBRecordReader

Answer (score 0):

This post talks about all that you want : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/

Comment: Yes, I read through it earlier but the number of DBRecordReaders that are being created are not yet clear to me...can you please explain ?